# List comparison in constraints for Minimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem, a simplified version of which is as follows:

```
x = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 7}];
A = {3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 6};
Minimize[{A.x,
  And @@ Thread[0 <= x <= 1] &&
   Plus @@ x == 3 &&
   x \[Element] Integers &&
   x != {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
  }, x]
```

Here, the sought-after solution is for `x`. The issue is that the solution when all but the last constraint (`x != {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}`) are used is exactly `{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}`. When I introduce the last constraint, there is no effect - I still obtain the same solution, although that constraint should remove that particular solution and output the next best one. If I replace the last constraint with `x == {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}`, then the output solution is exactly `{0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}`, so the comparison seems to be evaluated, but for some reason, the inequality given by `x != {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}` does not evaluate to `False`, although it should. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.sov

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Change your username to something meaningful! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works here (Mathematica v 9):

```
x = Table[Symbol[StringJoin["x", ToString[i]]], {i, 7}];
A = {3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 6};
Minimize[{A.x, (Apply[And, Thread[0 <= x <= 1]]) && (Apply[Plus, x] ==3) && 
         (x \[Element] Integers) && (x != {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0})}, x]
(* {8, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 1, x5 -> 0, x6 -> 0, x7 -> 0}} *)
```

But I would rather do something like:

```
Sort[{A.#, #} & /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

or

```
SortBy[Subsets[{3, 2, 5, 1, 7, 9, 6}, {3}], Tr@# &]
```

to get all results ordered at once

Comment: Thank you, the issue appears to be that the code here was using NMinimize as opposed to Minimize.

Comment: Another issue, however, is that Minimize no longer seems to work if A is a matrix of real numbers (e.g., A = {3.1, 2.1, 5.1, 1.1, 7.1, 9.1, 6.1})?

Comment: $$\text{Thank you}\\\text{for the}\\\text{helpful tip, beli}$$